# how to get the current page number from history in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using vs2010.

I used two link to back/forward between pages.

the code like,

```
 <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1);return false"><img src ="Images/back.jpg" /></a>
 <a href="#" onclick="history.go(1);return false"><img src ="Images/forward1.jpg" /></a>
```

it works well.
now i want to enable and disable links based on history like the browser window.

How to do this?
using vs2010 and JavaScript.

So, I have one idea.

I get total history length using history.length.
then I need to check the current page is the last page or not?
how to get the current page number from history in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely impossible. Let the user control their own browser, don't provide custom back and forward buttons unless you have control over the content.

Comment: Impossible because it would give away history information to any website you visit

Comment: Then how to disable forward button , if no more history available?

Comment: @Pooja: That's not possible, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show back and forward buttons only for the visited pages in your site, you can try this.

1. Save all visited urls of your site in one single cookie.
2. Read the cookie in each page and check your current page url position, then you can decide whether you can enable or disable your back and forward buttons.

Instead of cookies, you can also try html5 sessionstorage, but some browsers may not support this.